# Vim Ctrl v column selection issue on macOS Sierra

Tags: vim, macos-sierra

I am trying to use vim (Vi IMproved 8.0) on macOS Sierra for the first time and I noticed that a column selection in visual mode does not work properly.

Typing <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd> toggles visual mode on, and by moving left or right I can make a horizontal selection as usual.

For example, here I selected '***no play***' on the second line

[image]

However moving cursor down, instead of selecting a column, selects the current second line until the end and the next line is selected from the beginning to the cursor position.

[image]

I am guessing that this issue might be associated with the Terminal setting, rather than with bad settings in `.vimrc` since removing `.vimrc` does not change this behavior.

Moreover, I can `ssh` into a remote computer and still experience the same issue, even though vim on that remote computer works fine if I use a different computer to `ssh` into it.

I would appreciate any suggestions or tips on how to address or understand this issue.

Comment: Is ctrl button working fine in your keyboard ? Have you tried with `vim -u NONE file` ?

Comment: Use MacVim. There's no point in subjecting yourself to the limitations of terminal Vim anymore.

Comment: @Meninx-メネンックス @Andy Ray   thanks for suggestions. I have just tried your suggestions (`vim -u NONE file` and using `mvim`, but unfortunately I get the same behavior

Comment: @AndyRay @Menix looks like we are onto something! I googled `Ctrl` key not working properly and found that sometimes pressing `Shift Ctrl` makes it work. Indeed, if I press `Shift Ctrl v` in `mvim`, selection of columns starts to work properly. Unfortunately it still does not work in terminal `vim`.

Comment: Go to `System preferences > Keyboard > Modifier Keys`.   Try by selecting your keyboard and choosing  `restore defaults`

Comment: @Meninx-メネンックス thanks for suggesting `restore defaults`. But just after restarting the machine, I am still having to press a key `Fn Ctrl v` at least once in a Vim session to get `Visual Block` to work properly. After that `Ctrl v` works normally without having to add `Fn` key.

Comment: what about `Ctrl-q` to start a visual block ? Does it work as an alternative ?

Comment: @Meninx-メネンックス unfortunately `Ctrl-q` does not work, but actually the mitigation doing `restore defaults` and then having to press `Fn Ctrl v` worked fine for me. After that, the correct `Ctrl` action somehow got stuck in its settings and seem to have persisted one reboot.